# Forbid usage of the specifix index for the query

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

I have a mongodb collection with the following schema:

```
{
    "description": "some arbitrary text",
    "type": "TYPE",  # there are a lot of different types
    "status": "STATUS"  # there are a few different statuses
}
```

I also have two indexes: for "type" and for "status".

Now I run a query:

```
db.obj.count({
    type: { $in: ["SOME_TYPE"] }, 
    status: { $ne: "SOME_STATUS" }, 
    description: { $regex: /.*/ } 
})
```

MongoDB chooses to use an index for "status", while "type" would be much better:

```
"query": {
    "count": "obj",
    "query": {
        "description": Regex('.*', 2),
        "status": {
            "$ne": "SOME_STATUS"
        },
        "type": {
            "$in": [
                "SOME_TYPE"
            ]
        }
    }
},
"planSummary": "IXSCAN { status: 1 }"
```

I know I can use `hint` to specify an index to use, but I have different queries (which should use different indexes) and I can't annotate every one of them.

As far as I can see, a possible solution would be to forbid usage of "status" index for all queries that contain `status: { $ne: "SOME_STATUS" }` condition.

Is there a way to do it? Or maybe I want something weird and there is a better way?

Comment: Why do you think `type` would be much better?

Comment: It would be better only for my data, not in general. I have a lot of different types and condition `type=TYPE` would filter much more documents than `status!=STATUS`.

Comment: In general, `type=TYPE` should be more efficient, yes. But `type in TYPES` is a totally different beast. IIRC, it fires n parallel queries and merges the results. Maybe mongodb determined that it'd be faster to do just one ixscan instead of all this complicated flow.

Comment: Even if I specify `"type": SOME_TYPE` (strict equality) MongoDB still decides to use "status" index.